# Raw Material Button onPressed not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using an animated builder to build the layout. I use a Raw material button in the layout in the following manner

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPage2State createState() => _MyPage2State();
}

class _MyPage2State extends State<MyPage2>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
        vsync: this);
    _controller.forward() ;

    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      //  _controller.reverse(from:0.80);

      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyAnimatedPage(controller:_controller);
  }
}

class MyAnimatedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyAnimatedPage({@required AnimationController controller
  }) :animation = new MyPageEnterAnimation(controller);
  final MyPageEnterAnimation animation;

  double sHeight, sWidth;


  void _buttonPressed() {
    print('button pressed');
  }

  Widget _buildAnimation(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _buttonPressed();
            },
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            elevation: 4.0,
            shape: CircleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(width: 4.0, color: Colors.yellow)),
            fillColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            splashColor: Colors.indigo,
            highlightElevation: 3.0,
            highlightColor: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Text("+", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    sHeight = data.size.height;
    sWidth = data.size.width;

    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      /*  body: new AnimatedBuilder(animation: animation.controller,
          builder: _buildAnimation)*/
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('button');
            },
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            elevation: 4.0,
            shape: CircleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(width: 4.0, color: Colors.yellow)),
            fillColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            splashColor: Colors.indigo,
            highlightElevation: 3.0,
            highlightColor: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Text("+", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),),
          ),
          Text("Hello Button"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageEnterAnimation {

  final AnimationController controller ;
  final Animation<double> activityOpacity ;
  final Animation<double> logoXTranslation;
  final Animation<double> bannerXTranslation ;
  final Animation<double> sponsorsXTranslation ;

  MyPageEnterAnimation(this.controller) :
        logoXTranslation = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 2.75).animate(
          new CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: new Interval(
              0.200,
              0.500,
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        activityOpacity = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(

    new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: new Interval(
        0.500,
        0.700,
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  bannerXTranslation =
  new Tween(begin: 1560.0, end: 0.0).animate(
  new CurvedAnimation(
  parent: controller,
  curve: new Interval(
  0.730,
  0.900,
  curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
  ),
  ),
  sponsorsXTranslation = new Tween(begin: 360.0, end: 50.0).animate(
    new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: new Interval(
        0.900,
        1.000,
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
    ),
  );


}
```

However, the onPressed function _buttonPressed never gets called as the print statement never prints any thing.
I have even moved the entire Button code to the main build function, but still to no avail.
Where could I be making a mistake, please help.
Thanks

Comment: With "never gets called" you mean it's not called when you tap the button?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes it appears as if the function just doesn't gets called

Comment: i just go through your above code and it is working fine for me. are you using stack widget in you code anywhere then may be it is widget overlapping problem. if you are not using that then please add some more details and code.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya No, I am just using the above function as it is.

Comment: could you update the question with your complete source code ?

Comment: The button action onPressed is firing, but the print statement is not printing anything on the console. This seems to be the issue. (Android Studio, on Windows with an MiA2 device attached.).

Comment: I've copied your code of button and it works totally fine. How did you check that action onPressed is firing

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I put a navigation to a different route and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace:

```
onPressed: () {
_buttonPressed();
}
```

by this:

```
onPressed: _buttonPressed()
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Viren V mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457022/raw-material-button-onpressed-not-working/57103644#comment91859635_52457022):

> i just go through your above code and it is working fine for me. are you using stack widget in you code anywhere then may be it is widget overlapping problem. if you are not using that then please add some more details and code.

For me the problem was using a stack view with overflow set to overflow.visible where the button was located. changing it to overflow.hidden and then giving the stack height a given value gave me the desired design result and the button working again.